# Images is not loaded in jasper report while export the html pages

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am unable to shown the images when export the html using jasper reports.I tried to find out different solutions from this forums.But i didn't get any lucky and i need where can i missed out.I am sharing my code

jasper code :

```
    <parameter name="IMG_PATH" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>


<image>
<reportElement uuid="f4c3be1d-ec89-4e22-92c5-e75fbad2bcc5" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="567" y="2" width="174" height="56"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{IMG_PATH}+"\\logo.gif"]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Java Code:-

```
    rptExporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    rptExporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, byteArrayOutputStream);
    rptExporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); 
    request.getSession().setAttribute(ImageServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, jasperPrint);



    if (reportFrmType.equalsIgnoreCase("HTML")) {


                JRHtmlExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        rptExporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI,
                "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":"
                        + request.getServerPort() + ""
                        + request.getContextPath()
                        + "/resources/images/logo.png");

        rptExporter.setParameter(
                JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_OUTPUT_IMAGES_TO_DIR,
                Boolean.TRUE);

        rptExporter.setParameter(
                JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN,
                Boolean.FALSE);


    }
```

But i am not able getting the image and seen the Google Chrome > console and getting the images src like this

```
<tr valign="top">
  <td colspan="2" style="width: 292px; height: 43px;"></td>
  <td style="width: 4px; height: 43px;"></td>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="4"><img src="http://localhost:7005/SamplePortal/resources/images/logo.pngimg_0_0_5" style="width: 174px" alt=""></td>
</tr>
```

when i removed "img_0_0_5" from Googlechrome console then loading the image.why appended "img_0_0_5" in the src?

I tried another way and even i am not able get the image and check the console in chrome browser

```
<td colspan="2" rowspan="4"><img src="image?image=img_0_0_5" style="width: 174px" alt=""></td>
```

shared code below

web.xml:-

```
 <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.ImageServlet</servlet-class>  
  </servlet>
```

Java code :-

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(ImageServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, jasperPrint);
         Map imagesMap= new HashMap();  
         imagesMap.put("IMG_PATH", "wda-logo.png");
         request.getSession().setAttribute("IMAGES_MAP", imagesMap);

        if (reportFrmType.equalsIgnoreCase("HTML")) {

            rptExporter.setParameter(
                    JRHtmlExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");


             rptExporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_MAP,
                    imagesMap);
             rptExporter.setParameter(
                      JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, 
                      "image?image=");
            rptExporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_DIR_NAME,
                    "test");
            rptExporter.setParameter(
                    JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_OUTPUT_IMAGES_TO_DIR,
                    Boolean.TRUE);

            rptExporter.setParameter(
                    JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN,


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed out the context path in IMAGES_URI AND gave wrong in servlet mapping.I shared the code below

```
if (reportFrmType.equalsIgnoreCase("HTML")) {

            rptExporter.setParameter(
                    JRHtmlExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");



              rptExporter.setParameter(
                      JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, 
                      "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":"
                        + request.getServerPort() + ""
                        + request.getContextPath()
                        + "/servlets/image?image=");

           .....


        }
```

And web.xml

```
<servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/servlets/image</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks guys for supporting.